# Change background-color of the-radio-button | Element UI

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have an el-radio-button and I need to **change the background-color of the selected button**, which by default is bright blue.

I was trying this way:

```
<el-radio-group v-model="radio1">
      <el-radio-button label="New York"></el-radio-button>
      <el-radio-button label="Washington"></el-radio-button>
      <el-radio-button label="Los Angeles"></el-radio-button>
      <el-radio-button label="Chicago"></el-radio-button>
    </el-radio-group>
```

**CSS** (None has worked for me, it doesn't change the radio-group)

```
.el-radio-button__inner.checked {
  background-color: rgb(222, 233, 243);
  border-color: #409eff;
}
.el-radio-button__orig-radio.checked + .el-radio-button__inner {
  background-color: rgb(222, 233, 243);
  border-color: #409eff;
}
.el-radio-button__inner .is-active {
  background-color: rgb(222, 233, 243);
  border-color: #409eff;
}
```

[Codigo](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=f12ade93b34906683aceb5ef1005e36744109c88-1585148856-0-AdmjUPR5b9VOO8L9lCL0D3rsd-2BcGOE4tX5VEGR7KhjNq3w_fMiY1LkMIxdp0qyCENX6IENCuT207s1ABzHCj13RMGstpMli1nUxTkpC0bZc136ph4J45XBE7qJPrC2hADzSVKJktWTPzid3Gip92ocdZkXL6Ld2NLTObjAMadXilPZxMBlqrYwL6BCmkwXWCaoLF0ygChgJeSqI95Ukj5Z4_VurZpRzwcHxS2CYe256ks4FNqBd8GEyjby24fNoisr_Zr6nmskNpqLwe-fABxAVexG8ksQjbTNOhLLqTlOHhgIMv9lLbkSHirFnUKKOpZ-0zGaEZSo7HIWMAQwDPLMzprBbBWgSLvNgkz1tbVx)

Element reference: : https://element.eleme.io/#/es/component/radio

Comment: Use `!important` at the end of each line

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the second one and change it like below:

```css
.el-radio-button__orig-radio:checked + .el-radio-button__inner {
  background-color: rgb(222, 233, 243);
  border-color: #409eff;
}
```

You have used `.` before `checked` while you need to change it to `:` for checked.

`.(dot)` denotes a class while `:` is used for the states or `pseudo` usages.

Answer (score 0):

You can override css variables

```
.el-radio-button {
  --el-radio-button-checked-bg-color: blue;
  --el-radio-button-checked-text-color: white;
  --el-radio-button-checked-border-color: dark-blue;
  --el-radio-button-disabled-checked-fill: gray;
}
```